# Powerpoint reset animation and jump to another slide using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to build a PowerPoint presentation with a table of contents that is available from every slide. It's comprised of text hyperlinks that slides in from the side when a button on the page is clicked in Slideshow view. On clicking a link in the table of contents, two things need to happen: the presentation jumps to that slide, and the animation 'resets' so that if the user revisits the page they've just come from, the table of contents no longer appears on the page (as if it's returned to its starting point, out of view).

Typically animations don't "reset" in this way in Powerpoint, and an element such as a button or link seems to only be able to have one action assigned to it (either play an animation OR jump to a slide - not both). But I might be able to achieve this in VBA using the equivalent of an onLoad event?

I think there might be two routes:

1. Adding a script that resets any animations when a page is loaded. There are no other animations in the presentation that this would affect, and is probably the easiest solution if possible.
2. Adding actions to the hyperlinks in the table of contents, so that it both resets the animation and then jumps to the hyperlink. This might be problematic however as many non-power-users will be accessing the PowerPoint file - they will not be able to make adjustments to any scripts.

Answer (score 0):

> > so that if the user revisits the page they've just come from

How will they revisit the page? Ie, via a navigation link that you supply or by using arrow keys/keyboard? If the former, you can:

- Add another slide just before the one with the slide-in TOC text
  (make it a dupe of the one with the text, but delete the text).
- Set the slide to transition to the following slide automatically,
  after 0 sec delay.

PowerPoint will reset animations on arriving at a slide, but ONLY if you arrive from the previous slide, not from subsequent slides. This trick forces arriving from the previous slide.

Comment: Thanks Steve. You're right, that solution will work if I can control how users navigate to the page, but unfortunately that's not really feasible in this case. I found a solution that I'll post for others.

Comment: If you choose to set the slide show up in Kiosk mode, you can control the way the users navigate the presentation. You can give them whatever nav buttons/links you like and other than hitting ESC to exit the presentation, the user can't navigate in any of the normal ways (space bar/pageUpDown/etc)

Answer (score 0):

This VBA code will do the trick:

```
Public Sub App_SlideShowNextSlide(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
  ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.ResetSlideTime
End Sub
```

However, it will fire following any page transitions (e.g. fade), which may look odd.